# Why is this Question considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[This Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94477/latex-packages-in-wordpress?noredirect=1) was mistakenly migrated to [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82373/latex-packages-in-wordpress) and closed here. Questions in WPSE relating to WordPress.com-hosted blogs are clearly off-topic there, [per FAQ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq). So the Question was closed *there* because it's off-topic.

It seems like the Asker just wants to know if it's possible to integrate a LaTex package in their WordPress.com-hosted blog.

One correct Answer would be "*No, it's not currently possible. Post a feature request to WordPress.com to integrate that particular package.*"

Are Questions <del>relating to integrating</del> asking if  LaTex works with *Platform [X]* considered off-topic here? If so, I apologize in advance.

Comment: It's not always easy to know what will be on topic on another StackExchange site. As such, migration of material does happen such that the 'destination' site rapidly close things. That does not affect whether it's on topic for the 'source' site.

Comment: "It's not always easy to know what will be on topic on another StackExchange site." Actually, it is - *faq*. If us users are expected to follow faq, certainly Mods are, as well? :-Þ

Comment: The FAQ often don't tell the full story: the network is large and certainly I don't know the detail for all other sites. (You can't be sure how any particular question will be treated by another community: they may decide not to close something even if their FAQ suggests they might.)

Comment: As I said, the key question is whether something is on-topic for us, and that is not affected by whether it gets closed or migrated.

Answer (score 22):

Since the question is fundamentally about WordPress capabilities and not TeX (as evidenced by your suggested answer) it is off topic.  As for the "integrating LaTeX into Platform X" type questions, I think they would generally be off topic unless they specifically deal with the TeX side of things (such as how a particular TeX distribution works etc.)

Comment: Note that we do have for example [Is there any mathematical blog support latex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76502), which has been left open as it has some discussion of the TeX end, although it's certainly borderline.